# What is the property of neutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos

If mass of a particle is due to Higgs boson, spin is due to Z boson and translational energy is due to photons, what exactly is the innate property of a [neutrino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino)? If none exist, is neutrino truly a real particle or just a group of bosons?

Comment: Aren't neutrino's *fermions*? Do particles need to have "innate" properties?

Comment: The spin and momentum of a particle are affected by other interactions too, Z boson and photon don't have a special role there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a whole lot of questions wrapped up in two sentences.

I suggest you look at the standard model.   (see below) - and this one doesn't have the higgs, but it was hard to find one the right size to post.

[image: http://www.timeone.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/StandardModel.jpg]

All mass is a result of an interaction between particles with rest mass and the Higgs field or Higgs Boson if you like, but I think Higgs field is more correct.   Photons for example have 0 rest mass, so they don't interact with the Higgs field.

All particles have spin (again, see standard model), the Higgs Boson being the only exception.  It's the only particle without spin.

No particle is a group of bosons, at least, that I know of.   A boson can be a particle (photon) or more commonly, a boson is a temporary force carrying particle.

Quarks need to be bound with other quarks, so there are particles that are a group of quarks, the Proton for example.  But a proton isn't a fundamental particle.

The Neutrino is a lepton, so it is a "real" particle, like the electron but without charge.  It's also a fundamental particle - meaning, you can't define a Neutrino as made up of parts like you can a proton.    Neutrino's are also very elusive.  It doesn't interact with much.  That made Neutrino's hard to discover.    That's really the only thing a Neutrino and a Higgs Boson have in common, they were both very difficult to observe, but they were observed in very different ways.  They're really nothing alike.   They're about as different as 2 particles can be.

Hope that helps, just my quick answer to some of your questions.  I think this is a great site to get a quick overview of this stuff.   Much more info there than I can give you.   Pretty diagrams too.

http://www.particleadventure.org/

Answer (score 0):

They have weak hyperchage, flavor, mass and spin (though the mass states are not flavor states with various consequences). How many more "innate properties" do you want?

Comment: I think he means *do neutrinos do anything like the Higgs or Z boson* and not *what are its properties&

Comment: @KyleKanos yes.. and i am a 16 year old so please forgive me if i have given anything wrong in that question